# Javascript - Template Strings Don't Pretty Print Objects

Tags: javascript, string, ecmascript-6

Can I use ES6 template strings to pretty print javascript objects? This is from a React Native project, with `console.log()` outputting to Chrome debugging tools.

#### What I Want

```
const description = 'App opened';
const properties = { key1: 'val1', blah: 123 };
console.log('Description: ', description, '. Properties: ', properties);
```

outputs

[image: Pretty printing]

#### Template String Attempt

```
// Same description and properties
const logString = `Description: ${description}. Properties: ${properties}`;
console.log(logString);
```

outputs

[image]

#### Question

How do I get the first output (with the pretty printing) using template strings?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Your first example does not actually output a `string` to the `console`. Notice how `properties` is passed as a separate parameter argument (as it is surrounded by commas `,` and not string-concatenation operators `+`).

When you pass an `object` (or any JavaScript value) to `console` as a discrete argument it can display it how it wishes - including as an interactive formatted display, which it does in your first example.

In your second example, you're using templated-strings, but it's (generally) equivalent to this:

```
logString = "Description: " + description.toString() + ". Properties: " + properties.toString()";
```

And `Object.prototype.toString()` returns `"[object Object]"` by default. Note that this is a `string` value which is not particularly useful.

---

In order to get a JSON (*literally* **J**ava**S**cript **O**bject **N**otation) representation of an object used in a templated string use `JSON.stringify`:

```
logString = `Description: ${ description }. Properties: ${ JSON.stringify( properties ) }.`
```

Or consider extending `toString` for your own types:

```
myPropertiesConstructor.prototype.toString = function() {
    return JSON.stringify( this );
};
```

---

As a further improvement in modern browsers, you can render an interactive JSON object in your console output then you can use the `%o` [*string substitution* specifier](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console#using_string_substitutions) in your format-string, like so:

```
var foo = { a: 123, b: 'bar' };

console.log( 'Logged object follows this: %o - and some following text too', foo );
```

...which appears like this in Chrome's console:

[image]

...it's interactive, see:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

you can try out this `your message ${JSON.stringify(object)}`

Answer (score 3):

> Can I use ES6 template strings to pretty print javascript objects?

Sure, but you have to convert the object to a pretty printed version before you pass it to the template literal (I'm sure there are libraries out there that do that. The poor man's version is `JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2)`).

However, since `console.log` accepts an arbitrary number of arguments, you should just pass the object as second argument so that it doesn't get converted to a string:

```
const logString = `Description: ${description}. Properties:`;
console.log(logString, properties);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
const logString = `Description: ${description}. Properties: ${JSON.stringify(properties, null, 2)}`;
console.log(logString);
```