# "this" isn't working as I expected using string concatenation in Javascript

Tags: javascript

```js
const user1 = {
    name: 'Sherlock Holmes',
    address:{
        street:'Baker street',
        number:"221B",
    },
    sayMyAddress:function (){
        console.log(`My address is ${this.address}`)
        console.log(this.address)
    }

}

user1.sayMyAddress()
```

The result:

My address is [object Object]

{ street: 'Baker street', number: '221B' }

Why the `this` keyword shows the address value in the second case and doesn't in the first? the scope in this case isn't in the object user?

Comment: That has nothing to do with `this`. The same result can be observed with `console.log({})` and ``console.log(`${{}}`)``

Comment: Because in the first case you are transforming an object in to a string literal, so you get `[object Object]`, you can get the same result if do `console.log(this.address.toString())`. In the second case you set the first parameter to the console of the type object, so depending of the WB you would get the representation of the object

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript - Template Strings Don't Pretty Print Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46146860/javascript-template-strings-dont-pretty-print-objects)

Comment: If you implement the `toString()` function in `address` object, then the 1st `console.log()` would be able to print out the correct answer w.r.t the `toString()` defined.

Answer (score 2):

The result of the conversion of the address to a string is '[object Object]' as we'd expect. For example, if you do

```
console.log({}.toString())
```

you'll get an output of:

```
[object Object]
```

A small change in the code will give the desired result:

```js
const user1 = {
  name: 'Sherlock Holmes',
  address: {
    street: 'Baker street',
    number: "221B",
  },
  sayMyAddress: function() {
    console.log(`My address is ${this.address.number} ${this.address.street}`)
  }

}

user1.sayMyAddress()
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

You could also add a [`toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) function on the address object:

```js
const user1 = {
  name: 'Sherlock Holmes',
  address: {
    street: 'Baker street',
    number: "221B",
    toString() { return `${this.number} ${this.street}` }
  },
  sayMyAddress: function() {
    console.log(`My address is ${this.address}`)
  }

}

user1.sayMyAddress()
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

`this.address` is an object, so even if the `console.log` is sympatic enough to output the full object with values if you pass it the object directly, if you use it in a string you'll get `[object Object]`.

Just try it like this

```js
console.log(`My address is ${this.address.street} ${this.address.number}`)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to log the object itself. So the output result is pretty much expected.

Change the log line from:

```
console.log(`My address is ${this.address}`)
```

to:

```
console.log(`My address is ${this.address.street} ${this.address.number}`)
```