# Flex JavaScript Object - What Key:Values am I working with?

Tags: javascript, twilio, twilio-flex

flex.Actions.addListener accepts an event and passes an object into the Function, as detailed here:

[Add an Action after a Task is accepted](https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/developer/ui/actions#add-an-action-after-a-task-is-accepted)

console.logging the object just returns: [object Object] and JSON.stringify of the object returns: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON.

What is a good method to understand the structure of the object and the information that is available to me when facing the above?

Comment: Are you referring to the `payload` in the code example in the docs? It might be clearer if you put the exact sample code you're using to get both the `[object Object]` and the TypeError

Comment: So within the Functions, a couple objects are being passed it. I ended up just using intellisense,  some sample code I found and these links were quite helpful: https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/developer/ui/manager and https://assets.flex.twilio.com/docs/releases/flex-ui/2.0.0-beta.1/ and https://twilio.github.io/twilio-taskrouter.js/Worker.html

Comment: I just ran this exact example though and I'm not seeing what you're describing. I'm seeing the correct object in the console. To see `[object Object]` in a console.log is very strange, but in an `alert` it's very much expected. Are you 100% sure you were console logging and not alerting?

Comment: Yes, very sure. Using node v14.19.3. I can try again later this evening.

Comment: so in the template Flex Plug in, the code is like below. 

You can create a template Twilio Flex Plugin via:

`twilio flex:plugins:create --flexui2`

```
  async init(flex, manager) {

    console.log(`***Console Log of flex parameter: ${flex}`);
    console.log(`***Console Log of manager parameter: ${manager}`);
```

The console shows:
twilio-flex.unbundled-react.min.js:1566 ***Console Log of flex parameter: [object Object]
twilio-flex.unbundled-react.min.js:1566 ***Console Log of manager parameter: [object Object]
twilio-flex.unbundled-react.min.js:1566 Manager: ready to laun

Comment: It really is the same behavior with the other example I posted above. I believe because it is just a complex object?

Comment: Yep, I see your problem now. That's why I was trying to get the actual code you were using. You're taking the parameter object and converting it to a string by using the template literal syntax. If you just pass it as a second parameter to `console.log` I bet you'll see it work. `console.log('***Console Log of flex parameter:', flex)`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46146860/javascript-template-strings-dont-pretty-print-objects

Comment: Thanks @BrianThompson! That was it and I learned something new!